# If barley grains are too sprouted, how will this affect the beer?

Tags: beer, all-grain, first-time-brewer, malt, barley

I have 20 kilos of barley I placed on a wet large towel to germinate in order to obtain malt for beer. I let them too long and they sprouted too much[Look at the photos]. How will this long rootlets will affect the final product. Will it have too little sugar, or too much?

**I want to mention that it has a nice sweet smell, giving a smell of grapes, similar to the grape juice you make before becoming wine. It also has a fresh cucumber or watermelon smell.**

Are they unusable, do I need to feed them to the chickens and buy new ones? I guess if I dry them and remove the rootlets and the greens will be fine?
Bottom part:
[image: bottom]

Top part:
[image: top]

Comment: From things I found on the internet, that will really be unusable as malt. The starches will be converted to sugars in the kernel, and the sugars have delivered their energy in forming the roots and the acrospires.

When malting, the sprouts (acrospires) should not exceed three times the grain size.